# SQL JOIN + GROUPBY select data from row with MAX(Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I'm having trouble figuring out the solution to this SQL query.

### Schema

**Edit**: Adding Item Table

**Item Table**

- PK ItemID
- lots of other columns

**Linking Table**

- FK ItemID uniqueidentifier
- FK TransactionID uniqueidentifier

**Transaction Table**

- PK ID uniqueidentifier
- EntryDateTime DateTime
- (several other rows of int, varchar...)

**Edit** : I think I haven't made the relationships clear.  Each ITEM (table not shown) can have multiple transactions.  Multiple items can share the same transaction (hence the linking table).

*Please see the bottom for my current Query.  I have left this striked to show the progression of the question.*

<strike>I want to do something like this query.  The trick is I want the t.varchar and t.int columns to be whatever values are in the MAX(t.EntryDateTime) row.  I don't even know if group by is the right way to do this query.</strike>

```
SELECT lt.ItemID, MAX(t.EntryDateTime), t.varchar, t.int 
FROM LinkingTable lt
LEFT JOIN Transactions t ON lt.TransactionID = t.ID
GROUP BY lt.ItemID
```

This table is going to be joined against in this SQL query, so please try and give me the most performant solution .  Assume Table1 will contain millions of records.

```
SELECT 
(many columns)
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Table2ID = Table2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON ....
LEFT JOIN Table4 ON (Table2.ID = Table4.Table2ID and Table4.LocaleID = 127 and Table4.Type = 0)
LEFT JOIN **the query above** AS vTable1 ON  vTable1.ItemID = Table1.ID
WHERE Table1.CheckID IN (SELECT ID FROM Checks WHERE ....)
```

**Edit** : This is the query I have that **is working**, but I'm not sure its the most efficient.  LinkingTable has ~ 200k records and its taking 6 seconds to run.

```
SELECT DISTINCT lt.ItemID, t.EntryDateTime,  t.varchar, t.int
FROM LinkingTable lt 
     LEFT JOIN Transactions t ON t.id = (SELECT Top 1 t2.id FROM LinkingTable lt2
LEFT JOIN Transactions t2 on lt2.TransactionID = t2.ID
where lt2.ItemID = lt.ItemID ORDER BY t2.PrintTime DESC)
```

Comment: I see the max() from the "T" table, but what is the basis of that... max of everything, or the last entry per a given "ItemID", or per Transaction ID (doubt this one though).

Comment: In real speak, I want to do "Get all items, their latest transaction and a bunch of other information".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT i.*, outerT.EntryDateTime, outerT.varchar, outerT.int
FROM Item i
     LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ItemId AS outerItemId, EntryDateTime, varchar, int
      FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lt.ItemId ORDER BY t.EntryDateTime) AS RowNumber, lt.ItemId, t.EntryDateTime, t.varchar, t.int
            FROM Tranaction t INNER JOIN LinkingTable lt ON lt.TransactionId = t.ID) innerT
      WHERE RowNumber = 1) outerT ON outerT.outerItemId = Item.ID
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Unless I've made a mistake implementing this solution, its not working.  I actually don't see how its any different then a simple LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare I edited it, try it again and let me know if it works this time around

Comment: I may have been misleading when I said not working. It runs, its just not doing what I want.  The result table should have distinct ItemIDs.

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare let's try it one more time :D

Answer (score 1):

Even with a million plus records, you will have some performance hits, but I would ensure and index on the transaction table based on the ( ItemID, Primary Key ).  The reason Primary Key and not the date -- if its auto-incremented, and it's date/time stamped at time the transaction occurs, they will be in-essence, one-in-the-same.  The last entry in the file will always have the latest date.  That said, an ID column should be faster with index than a date/time.  This also prevents need of looking at BOTH elements of most recent date, and the transaction ID associated with that date.  Here is how I would FIRST attempt the query.

```
select 
      I.*,
      T2.*
   from
      Item I
         JOIN 
            ( select T.ItemID, MAX( T.PrimaryKey ) as LastEntryPerItem 
                 from Transactions T
                 group by T.ItemID ) MaxPerItem
            ON I.ItemID = T.ItemID

            JOIN Transactions T2
               on MaxPerItem.LastEntryPerItem = T2.PrimaryKey
   order by
      whatever
```

Comment: Transaction table does not have an ItemID field.  It is a many to many relationship between items and transactions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select lt.ItemId, t.entrydatetime, t.varchar, t.int
from LinkingTable lt
left join transactions t 
     on lt.transactionId = t.id
        and t.entryDateTime = (select max(t.EntryDateTime)
                               from transactions t2
                               where t2.id = t.id)
```

I had a similar question before
( [SQL Join to get value belong with most recent date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216753/sql-join-to-get-value-belong-with-most-recent-date)). There's another solution by JNK involving two joins which may be faster. I've posted below. You'll need to test to see which performs better.

```
select lt.ItemId, t.entrydatetime, t.varchar, t.int
from LinkingTable lt
inner join transactions t 
   on lt.ItemId= t.ItemId
Inner join (SELECT ItemId, MAX(entrydatetime) entrydatetime
            FROM transactions t2
            GROUP BY ItemId) SubQ
ON SubQ.ItemId= t.ItemId
AND SubQ.entrydatetime= t.entrydatetime
```

Comment: I believe both these solutions require the Transaction table to have the ItemID.  The Transaction table doesn't not have an ItemID field, as it is a Many <-> Many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a view that has all your "many columns" and then run a query against that view?